# Converting Tensorflow Tensor to PyTorch Tensor

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, tensor

I have been trying to convert a Tensorflow tensor to a Pytorch tensor. I have turned run eagerly to `true`. I tried:

```
keras_array = K.eval(input_layer) 
numpy_array = np.array(keras_array)
pytorch_tensor = torch.from_numpy(numpy_array)
```

I have also tried:

```
keras_array = input_layer.numpy()
pytorch_tensor = torch.from_numpy(keras_array)
```

However, I still get errors about converting the Keras tensor to a NumPy array. Here is the error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 364, in runcode
    coro = func()
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/benjaminschwartz/Apple Prediction.py", line 167, in <module>
    keras_array = K.eval(input_layer)
  File "/Users/benjaminschwartz/opt/anaconda3/envs/Prediction/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/backend.py", line 1634, in eval
    return get_value(to_dense(x))
  File "/Users/benjaminschwartz/opt/anaconda3/envs/Prediction/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/backend.py", line 4208, in get_value
    return x.numpy()
AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

I have also tried installing and reinstalling Tensorflow, Keras, Numpy, and Pytorch, with different versions, however, I am still getting this error.

Edit:

K is set

```
from keras import backend as K
```

Comment: tell us more about `keras_array` - type, etc

Comment: Can you specify your tensorflow and pytorch versions? Your first solution works in google collab just fine.

Comment: KerasTensors do not hold specific values, there is no value to convert to numpy array. I've seen this question too many times in the last few weeks. Also https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/18098

Comment: Thanks for this information. I have been trying different ways to convert the keras tensor to a tensorflow tensor but nothing seems to be working. Do you know how to do this.

Comment: There would be no way to convert it into TF EagerTensor either as KerasTensors are just placeholders.