# Converting Keras Tensor to Tensorflow Tensor

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use an Informer model from hugging face with a Keras model. This hugging face model, will not take a Keras tensor. Because of this, I am trying to convert this Keras tensor to a Tensorflow tensor then to a numpy array then to a Torch Tensor. However, I am having problems converting the Keras tensor to the TensorFlow Tensor. I have found different solutions online; however, when I get the type of tensor it is, it is still a keras tensor.

The input for the model is

```
input_layer = Input(shape=input_shape)
```

What I have tried from here is this

````
k_array = K.eval(k_tensor)

# Convert the Keras tensor to a NumPy array
n_array = np.array(k_array)

# Convert the NumPy array to a TensorFlow tensor with tf.convert_to_tensor
tf_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(n_array)```
````

I have run Eargly set to true. I have reinstalled tensorflow and keras. In addition to the way provided above I have tried numerous other ways, however, most of them using:

```
K.eval(some_value)
```

This is returning attribute error of

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 364, in runcode
> coro = func()
>
> File "", line 1, in  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
> pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)
>
> ## execute the script
>
> File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
> exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
>
> File "/Users/myname/Apple Prediction.py", line 292, in 
> k_array = K.eval(input_layer2)
>
> File "/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/envs/Prediction/lib/python3.10/ site-packages/keras/backend.py", line 1634, in eval
> return get_value(to_dense(x))
>
> File "/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/envs/Prediction/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/backend.py", line 4208, in get_value
> return x.numpy()
>
> AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Any help or an alternative solution would be very helpful.

Comment: looks a lot like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76245755/converting-tensorflow-tensor-to-pytorch-tensor

Comment: I didn't read the whole question. However, based on the title, they are trying to convert to a Pytorch tensor, and I am trying to convert to tensorflow tensor. I am relatively new to this. I do not know what the difference is. If that answers these questions then I will resolve this.

Comment: This is a XY problem, see https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: The common problem is that the `evaled` result can't be turned into a numpy array.  `K.eval()` is an unknown action - at least to us.